# Is there a rule in DnD 5e when buying starting equipement at higher level (lvl5 and higher)

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, wealth

is there some rules about the gold you can use when buying starting equipement at higher level.

My character just died and i have to create a new one at level five. My Game master is fairly new to the task and we got a debate about if you can use the extra 500+ 1d10x25 Gold piece you get in the starting equipement tab for buying starting equipement or not. (Page 36 dungeon master's guide)

My Game master doesn't know, and two of our players are arguing about a rule in the books that apparently mention that even at higher level you can only buy the starting equipement with the starting wealth by classe tab and not with any extra gold wathever the origine of it is even the starting equipement tab mentioned before. (player's handbook p. 143).

I've tried to find it in the Dungeon master's guide and online but could'nt find anythings about it. Even here the post about the starting equipement that i found doesn't mantion anything about it.

thanks for the light that you can bring in this zone of shadow.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Does the linked question address your question? If not, please edit your question to clarify how your question is unique/distinct from that one.